# UPDATE performance for empty join

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

I have this bit of sql

```
DECLARE @tmpTable TABLE(idTransaction int PRIMARY KEY, Value money)
DECLARE @idStatement int = 0

UPDATE T 
       SET idStatement = @idStatement
FROM tbl_Transaction T
INNER JOIN @tmpTable ST on T.id = ST.idTransaction
```

The table tbl_Transaction has about 250,000 rows in it (which i think is gunna be the cause of this), but when I run the query as it is it takes about 650ms to execute, even though the tmpTable is completely empty and the join will update no rows.

I am assuming this is something to do with how UPDATE works but can anyone shed any light on why? I know for an empty table I can check the row count but I am wanting to find out if this will affect the performance of my query when the tmpTable has rows in?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an index on the tbl_Transaction.id? If so, you should see an `Index Seek` in the execution plan, and it should be pretty fast. If you're seeing a table scan, that would definitely explain the performance.

Comment: tbl_Transaction does have an index on its id. I had completely forgot about the execution plan. On running that it actually seems to be an insert trigger I have on the tbl_Transaction that is having the biggest performance impact :\ I didnt even expect that to be the case as I wasn't actually doing an insert.

Comment: Triggers will fire even if you update a thing to be the same thing.  Therefore, you should add a where clause to your statement.  Where idStatement is NULL or idStatement <> @idStatement

Comment: @ChristopherTownsend can you let us know what happens when you use a temp table rather than a table variable (could it be to do with lack of stats on table variable)?

Comment: @ChristopherTownsend if the trigger has the biggest impact, then perhaps you could try IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM inserted) = 0 THEN RETURN as the first statement in your trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A trigger will fire even if you update to the same value

```
UPDATE T 
       SET idStatement = @idStatement
 FROM tbl_Transaction T
INNER JOIN @tmpTable ST 
   on T.id = ST.idTransaction 
  and idStatement <> @idStatement
```

if you need to also update to null

```
or (@idStatement == null and idStatement is not null)
```

And as stated in a comment try a #temp
Query optimization on Table is limited

Comment: They aren't even updating to the same value. They are updating zero rows. If the trigger is taking the time it must be doing something independent of the number of rows.

Comment: @MartinSmith See last paragraph

Comment: It's still an INNER JOIN on a table with zero rows. So when the trigger fires both INSERTED and DELETED tables will be empty. So the trigger won't do anything.

Comment: @AshleyLee See last paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

This is because it won't match indexes on the table variable the same way it will with a temp table. YOu could convert it to a temp table and that will most likely solve the problem. Alternatively, you could try this:

```
UPDATE T 
       SET idStatement = @idStatement
FROM tbl_Transaction T
WHERE T.id n IN (SELECT ST.idTransaction from @tmptable)
```

This will probably be slower than a temp table but faster than a join with a table variable